# How to use API in ol6 instead of map.getRenderer().registerLayerRenderers([Layer]) in ol5?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-6

In the API for openlayers V5.3.3 I used

`map.getRenderer().registerLayerRenderers([Layer])`

but its not working in openlayers V6, so i need to know how to use instead API in ol6,anyone can help me?